# Making image gallery, undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a tutorial to create an image gallery and it gives me an error on line 31 of the js file. Not familiar with jQuery language so I thought the code might be out of date. Tried using the migrate plugin and it still doesn't work. On the jQuery site it says .live() was removed and to use .on() instead but not sure how to do that.
html file:

```
   <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
            <nav id="navbar"></nav>
            </div>
        </header>

        <section id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <ul id="gallery">
                    <li data-tags="Web Design, Logo Design, Print Design"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/1.jpg"><img src="img/1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li data-tags="Logo Design"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/2.jpg"><img src="img/2.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li data-tags="Web Design"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/3.jpg"><img src="img/3.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li data-tags="Print Design"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/4.jpg"><img src="img/4.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li data-tags="Logo Design, Print Design"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/5.jpg"><img src="img/5.jpg"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <div class="container">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </section>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
        <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
        <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
        <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
        <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>           
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".fancybox").fancybox();
            });
        </script>
   </body>
```

javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var items = $('gallery li'),
    itemsByTags = {};

items.each(function(i){
    var elem = $(this),
    tags = elem.data('tags').split(',');

    elem.attr('data-id',i);

    $.each(tags,function(key,value){
        value= $.trim(value);
        if(!(value in itemsByTags)){
            itemsByTags[value] = [];
        }

        //add image to array
        itemsByTags[value].push(elem);

    });
});

//create all items option
createList('All Items', items);

$.each(itemsByTags, function(k, v){
    createList(k, v);
});

//click handler
$('#navbar a').live('click',function(e){
    var link = $(this);

    //add active class
    link.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    $('#gallery').quicksand(link.data('list').find('li'));
    e.preventDefault();

});

$('#navbar a:first').click();

//create the lists
function createList(text,items){
    var ul = $('<ul>',{'class':'hidden'});

    $.each(items, function(){
        $(this).clone().appendTo(ul);                      
    });

    ul.appendTo('#gallery');

    var a = $('<a>',{
        html:text,
        href:'#',
        data:{list:ul}
    }).appendTo('#navbar');
}
});
```

Comment: Did you try to just replace the _live_ with _on_ as the deprecation warning indicates?

Comment: That sort of fixed it. The images appear for a brief moment, then disappear. I have to quickly reload the page and click on an image in order for the image window to pop up. Once that happens the previous image, next image and close window functionality works properly.

Comment: Please study through the answer by _matthias_h_.

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting `live()` to `on()` can be done as follows: currently you have a statement like this:

```
$('#navbar a').live('click',function(e){ ...
```

and, as you already found out, `live()` is deprecated as of jQuery version 1.7.

Adjusting this to `on()` means to let the static `navbar` delegate the `click` event to `a` tags that are children of the `navbar`, even if they are added later:

```
$('#navbar').on('click', 'a', function(e){..
```

The `on()` is bound to an element that is already in the DOM when the page is loaded and delegates events to child elements even if they are dynamically added later.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/